# Problema estranho com RegisterClass

Tags: delphi

Estou com um problema muito estranho.

Tenho 2 projetos delphi, ambos estao com o build with runtime packages para false.

Ocorre que a procedure RegisterClass não funciona em um dos projetos, fazendo com que a function GetClass retorne nil para determinado form.

Alguem tem alguma dica ? Estou há horas pesquisando e não encontro nada.

Como disse, tenho outro projeto e num deles o RegisterClass funciona.

Alguém por favor me ajuda.

Comment: Os forms têm o mesmo nome de classe?
Não é possível, segundo a documentação, utilizar o mesmo identificador para chamadas distintas a `RegisterClass`.

Dá uma olhada no [link](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_RegisterClass.html) da documentação.

Comment: o problema nao é esse visto que nao tenho nenhum form com mesmo nome no projeto.